# Can this proof of the second MVT for integrals be salvaged?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

In the first edition of Spivak's *Calculus*, one of the exercises in the chapter on integrals (Ch. 13, Ex. 29) asks for a proof of the second (or Bonnet's) mean value theorem for integrals (although he calls it the third), in the form

> Suppose that $g$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Prove that there is a number $\xi$ in $[a,b]$ such that
>   $$ \int_a^b fg = g(a^+) \int_a^{\xi} f + g(b^-) \int_{\xi}^b f. $$

(I've changed the expression in the book to have $g(a^+)$ and $g(b^-)$ since $g$ may not be continuous.)

The proof the exercise appears to guide the student towards, and is exposited in the answer book, says that if we define the right-hand side as $h(\xi)$, then $h(a) = g(b^-) \int_a^b f = A $ and $h(b) = g(a^+) \int_a^b f = B$, and $h$ is continuous, so we can appeal to the intermediate value theorem and reduce the problem to showing that $\int_a^b fg$ lies between $A$ and $B$.

If we suppose $f \geq 0$ (*), this is straightforward:
$$ g(a^+)f(t) \leq g(t)f(t) \leq g(b^-) f(t) $$
and we integrate to get the result.

My actual question is: **can this proof be completed, to include the case when $f$ is not necessarily nonnegative?**

(There are other proofs, of course, but the use Riemann sums or the Riemann–Stieltjes integral, but this one is considerably simpler, at least up to this point)

---

(*) The answer book instead says to first assume that $g \geq 0$, and then the result follows by replacing $g(t)$ by $g(t)+c$. This clearly doesn't work: it is the sign of $f$ that we care about!

---

Two possibilities I have thought of:

1. Attempt Spivak's extension using $f(t)+c \geq 0$. This leads to the inequalities
   $$ A + cg(a^+)\int_a^b 1 \leq \int_a^b fg + c\int_a^b g \leq B + cg(b^-)\int_a^b 1 $$
   which are obviously not good enough since they give, for example, $ A \leq \int_a^b fg + c\int_a^b (g(t)-g(a^+)) \, dt  $ and the latter integral is positive, so the inequalities are too weak.
2. Splitting $f$ into positive and negative parts, $f=f^+-f^-$. This leads to some fairly baroque inequalities that are again too weak. **EDIT**: namely, $f^{\pm}$ are nonnegative, so the inequality proved for positive $f$ holds individually:
   $$ g(a^+) \int_a^b f^{\pm} \leq \int_a^b gf^{\pm} \leq g(b^-)\int_a^b f^{\pm}. $$
   Subtracting these in the only possible way that gives us $\int_a^b gf$ ("diagonally"), we find
   $$ A - (g(b^-)-g(a^+)) \int_a^b f^- \leq \int_a^b gf \leq B + (g(b^-)-g(a^+)) \int_a^b f^-, $$
   which is weaker than desired.

The first fundamental obstacle with both of these approaches seems to be that $\int_a^b f$ can be negative, which changes the order of $A$ and $B$ compared with that of $g(a)$ and $g(b)$. But the problem will persist on replacing $f \mapsto -f$, so it can't be the only obstacle.

Comment: I think that you mean to write $h(a) = g(b^-)\int_a^b f$, and similarly for $h(b)$.

Comment: @EricCanton True, although it doesn't make a material difference.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my previous comment since, as you point out, it was wrong. What goes wrong when we just apply the inequality mentioned by $f^+(t)$ and $f^-(t)$ separately?

Comment: @EricCanton I've added the results of that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems unlikely that we can extend this argument to cases where $f$ changes sign on $[a,b]$. We can easily construct examples where $\int_a^b fg$ does not lie between $A$ and $B$.

Let $g(x)=x$, $f(x)=\cos x$. On the interval $[0,\pi]$ we have
$$g(0)\int_0^\pi f=g(\pi)\int_0^\pi f=0$$

and $$\int_0^\pi gf=-2$$

In general, if $f$ changes sign on $[a,b]$, then $h$ can fail to be monotone so that $[A,B]$ (or $[B,A]$ depending on the size) might not be the whole image of $h$. Therefore it is possible that $\int_a^b gf$ does not lie in $[A,B]$ (or $[B,A]$), in which case the desired values of $\xi$ cannot be detected by IVT.

---

For any integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$, if we also fix the limits at the end points ($g(a^+)=u$, $g(b^-)=v$, so that $h$ is fixed), then by considering $g(x)=u\mathbf{1}_{[a,\xi]}(x)+v\mathbf{1}_{(\xi,b]}(x)$ we see that $\int_a^b gf=h(\xi)$. This shows that for any value in the range of $h$ there exists a suitable choice of $g$ s.t. $\int_a^b fg$ attains that value, so the best inequality that we could possibly prove in general is $\inf h(\xi)\le \int_a^b fg\le \sup h(\xi)$, which leads to the result by IVT, but then this would be the same as the Riemann sum proof.